# Why doesn't the heatmap of correlation matrix plot show the last row and column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Im trying to plot a correlation matrix. But for some reason, it doesn't plot the last row and column. I am really not sure what is going on here. The funny thing is that this problem occurs with both matplotlib and seaborn. The code, heatmap and correlation matrix ("correlations") are shown below. Can someone help me find the problem?

```
df = df_[cols]
correlations = df.corr(method='spearman')
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.matshow(correlations, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
ticks = np.arange(0, len(cols), 1)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(cols)
ax.set_yticklabels(cols)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90, horizontalalignment='right')
fig.tight_layout()
#sb.heatmap(correlations, xticklabels=cols, yticklabels=cols, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
plt.savefig(folder_ranges+'rankcorr.png')
```

[image: heatmap]

[image]

Comment: The second image have only 7 columns. May be there are some `NaN`. Where is `L2_hidden` in your second image?

Comment: Ooh. Wow it is really strange df.corr() seems to completely remove this column, eventhough there are no NaNs in the column. I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Got it! L2_hidden column eventhough gave a type=float, it seem to not be a numerical value. I converted the column to numeric with "df['L2_hidden'] = df['L2_hidden'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)" and now it works. Thanks for the help @Sheldore

Answer (score -1, accepted):

L2_hidden column eventhough gave a type=float, it seem to not be a numerical value, which df.corr() removed from the correlation matrix. I converted the column to numeric with "df['L2_hidden'] = df['L2_hidden'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)" and now it works.

Comment: like this? @Blastfurnace